# RegExp "g" flag not replacing every instance

Tags: javascript, regex, function, replace

I'm working on an EM to PX converter.  Basically you paste in your code in the "PX" textarea, and then the same code will appear in the "EM" textarea with em values.  It kinda works, but doesn't replace the value of all instances.  For example:  If you type "padding: 5px;" it will give you "padding: 0.313em;" successfully. However... if you put in "padding: 5px 4px;" it only replaces the "px" to "em" not the actual number values.

Try it out for yourself here :: http://jsfiddle.net/tJsNz/

```
        function pxToEm(){
        var px = document.getElementById("px"),
            em = document.getElementById("em"),
            parent = document.getElementById("parent-font-size");

        var pxVal = px.value.match(/\d+/ig);
        var pxToEm = 1 / parent.value * pxVal;
        var pxToEmFixed = pxToEm.toFixed(3);
        var pxToEmAnswer = px.value.replace(pxVal, pxToEmFixed).replace(/px/ig, "em");

        em.value = pxToEmAnswer;
    }
```

Comment: `pxVal` is an `Array` in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters). I think this is what you want - To find every match and replace based on it.

String's `.replace` method can accept a callback as a second parameter, and run that callback on every matches. You can run it and match all numbers then replace them with their translation value.

For a simpler example

```
var i=0;
"aaaaaa".replace(/a/g,function(match){
    return i++;
});
```

Will return `"012345"`. [Here is another example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example%3a_Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters)

In your case something like:

```
var pxToEmAnswer = px.value.replace(/\d+/ig, function(match){
    return 1 / parent.value * match;
}).replace(/px/ig, "em");
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/9Bw27/)

Comment: This is a good solution – but I'd suggest the following to avoid replacing numbers not followed by "px":

`var pxToEmAnswer = px.value.replace(/(\d+)px/ig, function(match, size) { return (1 / parent.value * size).toFixed(3) + "em" });`

Comment: Thanks!  That works out nicely.  Just out of curiosity, how is that function being called?  I'm guessing : .replace(/px/ig, "em");

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes Nice addition, I wanted to keep the code as similar to the original in the regex used but this is definitely correct. Especially if you want to match mixed values like `16px 13em` correctly - which the current code does not do.

Comment: @MattKnowsTech You pass a function as an argument to replace. `.replace` can either get a function or a string as a second parameter. If that parameter is a function it'll call that function for every match and replace with the function's returned value.